# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.linear_model._base' - Why found this error on my ec2 ubuntu cloud server?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scikit-learn

On my AWS ec2 cloud server(ubuntu) when I run the **server.py** file to run my server then is showed me the below error:

```
File "server.py", line 31, in <module>
    util.load_saved_artifacts()
  File "/home/ubuntu/HousePricePrediction/server/util.py", line 39, in load_saved_artifacts
    __model = pickle.load(f)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.linear_model._base'
```

Answer (score 0):

The model was created on a different system with a different version of sklearn.
After finding this error then I checked the scikit-learn version.

**Check the current version:**

```
sudo pip3 list scikit
```

> Note: If your os isn't ubuntu then remove 'sudo'. And if you are
> using 'conda' then use 'conda' instead of pip3.

Then I found the current version `scikit-learn (0.20.3)` and realized that maybe this version is backdated or not suitable for the system. Then I upgrade scikit-learn.

**Upgrade scikit-learn:**

```
sudo pip3 install -U scikit-learn
```

After that, I again run my server.py file to run the server and my server successfully runs.

> Note: If your system needs a specific version of the 'scikit-learn' library for your system
> then use this command:

`sudo pip3 install scikit-learn=0.17` - (for example)